# ggplot cuts date off before data ends

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

ggplot won't plot entire data on x-axis (date) Date goes to 6/24/2020.

```
COVID1<- read.csv("RStudioEx1.csv")
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
filter(COVID1, COUNTY == "Alcona" & CASE_STATUS == "Confirmed" & Date >= "3/1/2020")
my_cases <- filter(COVID1, COUNTY == "Alcona" & CASE_STATUS == "Confirmed" & Date >= "4/1/2020")
ggplot(my_cases)+
 geom_col(aes(x = Date, y = Cases))+
scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = TRUE))+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))+
labs(title = "Alcona Cases")
```

**Screenshot :**

[image: ref]

Comment: Please `dput(COVID1)` and include in your question in order to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't show you the plot output without data to confirm this works, but looking at your plot you can see that the x axis is not formatted as a date, but as a character string.  This means you need to format `COVID1$Date` as a date first, then proceed with the `filter()` and `ggplot()` functions.

Try this before your `filter(...` line:

```
COVID1$Date <- as.Date(COVID1$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed to keep plugging along. The Dates are now all in the proper format to be read as dates as I can see by running the filter!

Comment: For formatting of the axis, I would suggest using a `scale_x_date()` line.   Combine this with the `scales` package and you will be able to use `date_format` and `date_breaks` for the `labels=` and `breaks=` arguments to put together some nice scales.  [Documentation on scales_date functions here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html)

Comment: #Awesome
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%d"), breaks = "2 day")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))+